# Android - No properties for TextView in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever I go to graphical layout in my `activity_main`, and click TextView, or anything besides the main layout I have the little properties box says `<No properties>`. I tried restarting Eclipse, but nothing happened. This started after I went to `eclipse.ini` and changed the RAM allocation.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

**EDIT:** I just noticed, the entire top part is gone as well:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGhsw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change current API version in top of XML editor(Green android robot spinner).Choose API 18 or lower.It should re-render the layout for a lower API Level and you should find it working fine.